# Any suggestions to speed up slow geography query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, geography

We have a table of Customers, with each one's location as a Geography column, and a table of Branch Offices also with each one's location as a Geography column *(we populate the Geography columns from latitude and longitude columns)*

We need to run a query (view) that's intended to show the closest branch office to each customer, based on Geography columns, and it runs fine with a couple of thousand customers. We just received a big job that needs to run with 700,000 customers and it takes ***hours*** to run. Can anyone suggest any ways to speed up this SQL?

```
WITH CLOSEST AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (
        PARTITION BY CustNum
        ORDER BY Miles
    ) AS RowNo 
    FROM 
(
SELECT 
CustNum,
BranchNum, 
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 6), (BranchLoc.STDistance(CustLoc)) / 1609.344) AS Miles
FROM 
Branch_Locations
CROSS JOIN
Cust_Locations
) AS T
)
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT CustNum, BranchNum, Miles, RowNo FROM CLOSEST WHERE RowNo = 1 ORDER BY CustNum, MILES
```

Could there be a way to put the distance comparison into the JOIN? Nothing comes to mind so far...

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: It would probably help to show the schema of all involved tables, including any indexes, etc.

Comment: In general, you don't optimize queries by just shifting parts around (if the original logic is sound, and the updated version is logically equivalent, then if the optimizer is doing its job right then the updated version should produce the same execution plan as the original). The main optimization tool in SQL is indexes. Do you have spatial indexes defined on your tables?

Comment: Reduce the initial population to test.  Take a peek at "Item 2"  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869613/handling-very-big-table-in-sql-server-performance/45870223#45870223

Comment: Cross join is a performance killer, I would try to do some inner join but without knowing the table structure and definition it’s hard to help.

Comment: Tables are pretty simple: Cust_Locations has CustNum (integer, PK) and CustLoc (geography), Branch_Locations has BranchNum (integer, PK) and BranchLoc (geography). There are no Spatial Indexes; should there be?

Comment: Can you apply additional constraints, e.g. a bounding box by lat./long. beyond which you don't need to look (as Dr. Cappelletti suggested)? (Indexed persisted computed columns may help.) Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Is this a one-time event or will it be done repeatedly? If the latter then it may make sense to keep the results and maintain them via triggers on the `Branch_Locations` and `Cust_Locations` tables.

Comment: Not sure the final use, but the easiest way to achieve this is preload a table with a setup like Location Range, Closest Location. Then it would be a basic inner join and done.

Comment: We receive new data from clients regularly (weekly and monthly), each with a list of offices and a list of customers or prospects, all with latitude and longitude data, and they want us to generate a list of each customer/prospect and the 1, 2 or 3 closest branch offices.

Comment: Hi Damien... yeah I was kinda wondering if maybe there was a better way than the CTE and partition the way I was doing it.

A guy I work with wrote a version using Haversine math calculations with the latitudes and longitudes instead of the built-in Geography:STDistance calls, and it runs like 20x faster....what the heck is wrong with Microsoft's code that its own internal Geography data calculations are so slow?

Comment: @BrianBattles If haversine is faster, I would hazard a guess it has to do with how you are implementing Geography rather than the method itself.  The geography data type is a CLR function inside SQL Server which means that to process any geography method an external DLL has to be loaded; this is, in my experience, the most common cause of SQL Spatial being slow,  If you do your operations set based, this only has to happen once, but if you do it another way, such as an inline query, it will load and unload many times, causing your logic to grind to a halt.

Answer (score 0):

So, what you're doing here is calculating the distance from each point to each other point, then ranking.  SQL Server Spatial is actually set up in such a way that this is entirely unnecessary.

The first thing you want to do is make a spatial index on each table; documentation on how to do this can be found [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-spatial-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  Don't worry too much about the specific paramters here, while you can definitely improve performance by adjusting them, having a spatial index *at all* will drastically improve performance.

The second thing you want to do is to make sure the spatial index is being used; documentation on how to make sure this happens can be found [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/query-spatial-data-for-nearest-neighbor?view=sql-server-2017)  *Make sure that you filter out any null spatial information!*

So, what this has told as so far is a way to take a point and find the closest point in another long list of tables; but this is SQL Server, we want to to this set based!

My recommendation is to use a little a priori knowledge and write a query using that.

```
WITH CLOSEST AS (
  SELECT 
    C.CustNum,
    B.BranchNum, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.CustNum ORDER BY B.BranchLoc.STDistance(C.CustLoc)/1609.344 ASC) AS Miles
  FROM 
    Branch_Locations B
  INNER JOIN
    Cust_Locations C
  ON
    B.BranchLoc.STDistance(C.CustLoc)/1609.344 < 100 --100 miles as a maximum search distance is a reasonable number to me
  WHERE
    B.BranchLoc IS NOT NULL
    AND C.CustLoc IS NOT NULL
) AS T

SELECT 
  CustNum, 
  BranchNum, 
  Miles, 
  RowNo 
FROM 
  CLOSEST 
WHERE 
  RowNo = 1 
ORDER BY 
  CustNum, 
  MILES
```

There are other techniques that you can use, such as my response [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303682/sql-server-geography-search-performance-query-nearest-stores/41388643#41388643) however at the end of the day the most important takeaway is to create spatial indexes and *make sure they are used.*